# Создание оконных приложений на C++ в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c#, delphi, visual-basic

Как в Visual Studio рисовать окна на С++?

- В Basic есть Form Application
- В Delphi есть Form Application
- В Borland С++ есть Form Application

Где в Visual Studio есть нечто похожее, а не прошлый век MFC?

С# - это не то. Мне нужно, чтобы на выходе был чистый EXE. Который бы работал бы без NET. Например, на Windows XP 2006 года. Короче, нужно чтобы, получалась обычная программа как, например, в Delphi 7.

Есть такое в Visual Studio? И что заюзывать, чтобы такое было?

Comment: кому он нужен MFC, когда сейчас главное быстро написать приложение и продать?
не то время уже

Comment: @sdgdfshfgshdf Ну, успехов вам в продаже ваших приложений.

Comment: Вы скажите, как ваша контора называется, чтобы я нечаянно не купил.

Comment: > Мне нужно, чтобы на выходе был чистый EXE

Попробуйте `windows.h`, говорят, хорошая штука. Вот @Котик_хочет_кушать  не даст соврать.

Comment: короче как я понял, написать вспомогательные програмки на С++ не удасться за минут 30

хватит минусовать лучше напишите в чем можно разрабатывать на qt чтоб не пользоваться вишуал студио
какие есть профессиональные ide чтоб обходиться без студио?

установил 2012 профессиональную, только оформление поменяли
тоже самое в 2005 было

Comment: QtCreator?

Answer (score 4):

- "Чистый" `VCL Forms Application` на `Delphi 7` тянет с собой кучу веселых файлов типа `rtl70.bpl`.
- Если откинуть дотнетовские `WinForms` и `WPF` (и если не пользоваться сторонними штуками типа `Qt / wxWidgets`), то выбор обычно стоит между `MFC, WTL` или чистым `WinAPI`.

Comment: хорошо что стоит а не привстает

а как на счет линукса?

мне нужно чтобы я мог программу запускать не только на винде

Comment: @sdgdfshfgshdf Вы забыли добавить в ваш комментарий картинку "Отличная шутка".

Comment: @sdgdfshfgshdf, [посмотрите](http://www.bin-co.com/tcl/tutorial/legal.php), вдруг понравится?

Кстати, встраивается в Си (а в linux можно наладить взаимодействие между модуями по pty).

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать
> "Чистый" VCL Forms Application на Delphi 7 тянет с собой кучу веселых файлов типа rtl70.bpl.
Это если только специально зайти и галочку поставить. С билдером не путаем?

Comment: @KoVadim

- Ну имелось ввиду, что даже в случае выключенной "галочки" к `exeшнику` пустого `Forms Application'а` статически линкуются все используемые `VCL` компоненты (то есть неявно все эти `rtl70.bpl` присутствуют в конечном приложении).

- Или я что-то напутал?

Comment: значит так и нужно писать.

Линкуются или нет - топикстартера это точно не волнует. Ему важен один файл.